# Body parsing (Superagent, Discord.js)

Tags: discord.js, superagent

I want to know how can i parse urls like this into my superagent:

["https://cdn.shibe.online/shibes/798c20a027fc06869366a549187ea85885737361.jpg"],

kJBTm.jpg at http://random.birb.pw/tweet/

I am beginner, sorry. I know only the very basics of Discord.js

```
const {body} = await superagent.get ....
```

I want it in the embed like

```
let testEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor("color")
  .setTitle("title")
  .setImage(body.url);

  message.channel.send(testEmbed);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const superagent = require('superagent');

let { text } = await superagent.get('http://random.birb.pw/tweet');
// console.log(text);
let testEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setColor("0x000000")
.setTitle("title")
.setImage(`https://imgur.com/${text}`);
message.channel.send(testEmbed);


// using node-fetch
const fetch = require('node-fetch');

let { file } = await fetch('http://random.birb.pw/tweet.json').then(body => body.json()); // getting "file" object from fetched body
// console.log(file);
message.channel.send(`https://imgur.com/${file}`);
let testEmbed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
.setColor("0x000000")
.setTitle("title")
.setImage(`https://imgur.com/${file}`);
message.channel.send(testEmbed);
```

Don't use that api, 70% of images I was getting was deleted from imgur